How to migrate a Room database when a column has to get added to an @Fts4 entity?
I am using Room (version 2.6.1) with a @Fts4 annotated @Entity to support full text search (which works perfectly well).
This is my entity and this is the version that Room automatically created to initialize my database.
I now want to add a new field to my entity that should also get indexed via FTS and followed the doc to create an automatic migration.
The problem is that since the FTS tables are virtual tables they can't be altered, so any automatic migrations fail.
I tried writing a manual migration then by dropping and recreating the FTS table like this:
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recipes_fts;");
            database.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes_fts USING FTS4(title, description, source, ingredients, notes, tokenize=unicode61 `tokenchars=#`, content=`recipes`);");
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE recipes ADD COLUMN notes TEXT;");
        }
    };

I have the following problems with that:

I would also have to drop and recreate the triggers that Room created for the initial version and rebuild the FTS table which is all kind of messy and defeats the purpose of using Room for me
When using manual migrations I run into this issue and haven't found a way to solve it yet
Using the database inspector reveals that there are a lot of FTS related tables generated automatically (see shadow tables in the FTS doc) and I'm not sure if it is save to drop these too

How do people usually do migrations with Room when FTS is involved?

In my case it was a migration when I didn't have fts entity and need to add it. Not like in yours (when need add a field). But maybe it helps.
I have TestEntity and TestFtsEntity, here is the log I got after running without migration:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly
handle: TEST_FTS_TABLE(test.example.entity.TestFtsEntity).

Expected:
FtsTableInfo{name='TEST_FTS_TABLE', columns=[TEST_NAME, TEST_TEXT], options=[content=`TEST_TABLE`]'}
Found:
FtsTableInfo{name='TEST_FTS_TABLE', columns=[], options=[]'}


TEST_NAME and TEST_TEXT are fields
TEST_FTS_TABLE and TEST_TABLE are tables names (obviously)

Migration in my case was:
// Drop incorrect table if needed
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_FTS_TABLE")

// Create new one for fts
database.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_FTS_TABLE USING FTS4(NT_NAME, NT_TEXT, content=`TEST_TABLE`)")

// Retrigger fts to rebuild
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO TEST_FTS_TABLE(TEST_FTS_TABLE) VALUES ('rebuild')")

And it works out! Also I found someone's snippets, it was really helpful: github link

Thanks for your input! Did you explicitly add any triggers? For now I decided to just not index the new field, which is a shame...

No, I didn't add anything else, that's all
